# Continue Batch File even if path/target used in START command is wrong

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I run this :
`START "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath" & ECHO Something` 
an error message box appears as :
[image]
Now cmd does not execute `echo something` (or rest of the code, if any) until user clicks "OK" or "Close" of message box.
Is there any way to execute rest of the commands/batch file without pressing "OK" or "Close" of error message box?

Note : I don't want to use `IF EXIST UnavailableFileOrPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ...

`start /b cmd /c start "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath" >nul 2>&1 & ECHO Something`

This exactly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start call start "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath" & ECHO Something
```

This is open another command prompt window and execute the `start "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath"` portion, then process the rest of the command `& ECHO Something` in the original window.

Comment: Ok, it answered my question, but second cmd prompt is a headache (even minimized), and Now if I click OK of error message box, second cmd prompt still remains open until I explicitly close it.

Comment: Ok, I think this would be something better, start /min cmd /c start "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath" & ECHO Something.  It starts target with minimized extra cmd prompt and ALSO if "OK" or "Close" of error message box is clicked, extra cmd disappears from taskbar. (and obviously echo something is there already in parent cmd window.) Thanks Alex... And if anyone has any idea to suppress this extra cmd prompt, they are welcome.

Comment: This eliminates the problem of extra cmd prompt : start /b /min cmd /c start "Title" "UnavailabeFileOrPath" & ECHO Something , But one extra message is coming on parent cmd window "The system cannot find the file UnavailabeFileOrPath", probaly from child (second) cmd prompt. Any way to remove this ?

Comment: Finally, I posted my solution which fulfills all requirement.